# External hard drive not recognized on USB 2.0 port

Tags: usb, external-hdd

I bought a **Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex Desk 2 TB external drive** two years ago and used the drive with Ubuntu and Windows (dual boot workstation).

I made a backup of the drive last week using another computer with Ubuntu. The drive was plugged into an USB 2.0 port. This worked fine. Today I tried to make a new backup but the drive is not recognized on any USB 2.0 port using Ubuntu on the notebook and the workstation. However it works fine with an USB 3.0 port on the workstation using Ubuntu and with an USB 2.0 port on the workstation using Windows.

### **`dmesg` output on USB 2.0 port:**

```
[ 2639.918220] usb 3-13: new full-speed USB device number 35 using xhci_hcd
[ 2640.030106] usb 3-13: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2640.245928] usb 3-13: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2640.461606] usb 3-13: new full-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
[ 2640.573492] usb 3-13: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2640.789330] usb 3-13: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2641.004971] usb 3-13: new full-speed USB device number 37 using xhci_hcd
[ 2641.005104] usb 3-13: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2641.208798] usb 3-13: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2641.412467] usb 3-13: device not accepting address 37, error -71
[ 2641.524357] usb 3-13: new full-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
[ 2641.524508] usb 3-13: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2641.728214] usb 3-13: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2641.931861] usb 3-13: device not accepting address 38, error -71
[ 2641.931904] usb usb3-port13: unable to enumerate USB device
```

### **`dmesg` output on USB 3.0 port:**

```
[ 2688.506387] ata1: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
[ 2688.506390] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2688.506391] ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[ 2688.506394] ata1: hard resetting link
[ 2689.228700] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 2689.233180] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2689.240693] ata1: EH complete
[ 2689.614377] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[ 2689.614382] ata1: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
[ 2689.614384] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 2689.614386] ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[ 2689.614390] ata1: hard resetting link
[ 2690.335405] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 2690.339904] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2690.341259] ata1: EH complete
[ 2693.256367] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 2693.272790] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=50a1
[ 2693.272792] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 2693.272794] usb 4-2: Product: FA GoFlex Desk
[ 2693.272794] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 2693.272795] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXX
[ 2693.273197] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2693.273284] scsi11 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[ 2694.271915] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  FA GoFlex Desk   0D12 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 2694.272073] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 2694.272604] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[ 2694.272791] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 2694.272793] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 2694.273309] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 2694.273311] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2694.290407]  sdc: sdc1
[ 2694.314947] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I found this, I don't know what it should be doing, but hey, why not try it: `echo Y > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/old_scheme_first`

Comment: Counter-intuitively, "new full-speed USB device" means the device is getting detected as a USB 1 device. The original USB 1 specification had two speeds: "low" and "full". When USB 2 was introduced, the new speed was called "high speed", and USB 3 brought "super speed".

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797789) you can find a similar problem solved. The main idea is to disable autosuspend in the usbcore, if I got it right.

Try executing

```
echo -1 >/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

And reboot the system afterwards. This one helped the guy from ubuntu forum

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working. :( I also tried `cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
` after reboot but it displays the old value (2).

Comment: Try look into [this thread](http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1445313.htm). These ([1](http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1445313.htm#post5520372), [2](http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1445313.htm#post5520364)) answers might be helpful to you.

Comment: THIS WORKED WITH MY YETI BLUE that stopped working on two Windows machines, and a Ubuntu one. HOLY CRAP you're an angel.